# Data normalization and rescaling value in Python

Tags: python, pandas, normalization, sklearn-pandas, feature-scaling

I have a dataset which contains URLs with publish date (YYYY-MM-DD), visits. I want to calculate benchmark (average) of visits for a complete year. Pages were published on different dates.....e. g. Weightage/contribution of 1st page published in Aug (with 10,000 visits) will be more as compare to 2nd page published in March (11,000).

Here is my dataset:

[image: Click here to see my dataset]

First step:

So first of all I want to add a column (i.e. time frame) in my data set which can calculate the time frame from the Publish date. For example: if the page was published on 2019-12-10, it can give the time frame/duration from my today's date, expected o/p: (**Dec 2019, 9 Months**). i.e. (**Month Year on which the page was published, Total months from today**)

Second step:

I want to **normalize/rescale my data (visits)** on the basis of calculated time frame column in step 1.

How can I calculate average/benchmark.

Comment: In the second step, you want to have a table that shows the average of visits in the year?

Comment: Yes, i want to calculate average on the value on the basis of months you calculated  in step1. I'm also getting error in step 1 while running code:- 
  File "<ipython-input-20-5ceae8ed6c80>", line 14, in normalize_date
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # get datetime object

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not numpy.datetime64

Comment: So per month, maybe there are multiple visits records?

Comment: I modify the answer to support the average!

Comment: I'm getting this error message..... File "<ipython-input-10-3c9d5399e770>", line 3, in normalize_date
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # get datetime object

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not numpy.datetime64

Answer (score 0):

for the first step you can use following code:
read dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("your_df.csv")
```

My example dataframe as below:

```
            Pub.Dates Type  Visits
0  2019-12-10 00:00:00    A    1000
1  2019-12-15 00:00:00    A    5000
2  2018-06-10 00:00:00    B    6000
3  2018-03-04 00:00:00    B   12000
4  2019-02-10 00:00:00    A    3000
```

for normalizing the date:
at first define a method to normalize just a date:

```
from datetime import datetime

def normalize_date(date): # input: '2019-12-10 00:00:00'
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # get datetime object
    date_to_str = date_obj.strftime("%B %Y") # 'December 2019'
    diff_date = datetime.now() - date_obj # find diff from today 
    diff_month = int(diff_date.days / 30) # convert days to month
    normalized_value = date_to_str + ", " + str(diff_month) + " months"
    return normalized_value # 'December 2019, 9 months'
```

now apply the above method to all values of the date column:

```
df['Pub.Dates'] =list(map(lambda x: normalize_date(x), df["Pub.Dates"].values))
```

The normalized dataframe will be:

```
                  Pub.Dates Type  Visits
0   December 2019, 9 months    A    1000
1   December 2019, 9 months    A    5000
2      June 2018, 27 months    B    6000
3     March 2018, 31 months    B   12000
4  February 2019, 19 months    A    3000
5       July 2020, 2 months    C    9000
```

but for the second step if there are multiple records per month you can do the following steps, `groupby` date and other columns you need then get mean of them:

```
average_in_visits = df.groupby(("Pub.Dates", "Type")).mean()
```

the result will be:

```
                               Visits
Pub.Dates                Type        
December 2019, 9 months  A       3000
February 2019, 19 months A       3000
July 2020, 2 months      C       9000
June 2018, 27 months     B       6000
March 2018, 31 months    B      12000
```

Comment: Thanks Maryam for helping me in first step, I'm getting this error while running the same code. Please help 
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # get datetime object

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not numpy.datetime64 .....................For second step what more information do you need?

Comment: you should pass each element of date column to the `normalize_date` method, because its input is just string. please run this part of code:`df['Pub.Dates'] =list(map(lambda x: normalize_date(x), df["Pub.Dates"].values))` it runs the normalize_date method for every element and return the list of new dates.